# Get tables list from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've just started learning php.

I am trying to get a list of tables from my database. what I have tried -

```
<?php   
    $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "");
    $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM MyDatabase";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "Table: {$row[0]}\n"; //error here
    }
?>
```

But it does not show tables and returns - `Notice: Undefined offset: 0`.
Any help?

Comment: There is no `0` index in your `$row` array because you are calling `$result->fetch_assoc()`. Try changing the call to `$result->fetch_array()`

Comment: @Nick Bingo.its working like a charm. Please make it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `0` index in your `$row` array because you are calling [`fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) which returns an array with associative keys. Try changing the call to [`fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) which will return a numerically indexed array, or [`fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) which will return an array with both numeric and associative indexes. e.g.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `fetch_array()` inplace of `fetch_assoc()`

`fetch_array()` returns one array with both numeric keys, and associative strings (column names), so here you can either use `$row['column_name']` or `$row[0]`

Where as `fetch_assoc()` will return string indexed key array and no numeric array so you won't have an option here of using numeric keys like `$row[0]`.

Change just below code -

```
<?php   
    $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "");
    $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM MyDatabase";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
       echo "Table: {$row[0]}\n";
    }
?>
```